# Intel HD 4600 running slow

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

Merhaba,

I recently bought a laptop with Intel HD 4600 integrated graphics card. I installed Ubuntu 14.04, installed Intel drivers using Intel Graphics Installer for Linux.

My problem is when I am watching a flash video it is slow. When opening dashboard it is also slow as hell. So I researched about the problem. Then found this solution below.

Creating a /etc/X11/xorg.conf and adding the configs below

```
Section "Device"

Identifier "Card0"

Driver "intel"

Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"

#Option "AccelMethod" "sna"

EndSection
```

So problem with this is when I created and used this and reboot. My screen is closed. Completely blank. It is like closed and no power. So If I go to recovery mode and select fsck option then abort it with Ctrl + c. Then it starts unity screen is on and my problems are also gone.

I think I need to update grub and/or add some kind of parameters to it.

Thanks,